# how to send value to servlet from dynamically text box created

Tags: javascript, java, database, jsp, servlets

How to pass value from jsp to servlet ?
In Jsp there is input box which is dynamically created.

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Qty" min="0" 
     onkeypress="return newTextBox(event)">
```

this line is in html through which textbox is created.

```
<script>
/* starts here for the dynamic page*/
var instance = 0;

function newTextBox(event) {

    instance++;
    var x = event.which || event.keyCode;
    if (x == 13) {

        var table = document.getElementById('tableOne');

        var rowCount = document.getElementById('tableOne').rows.length;

        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);

        // cell1 starts here//
        var newInput1 = document.createElement("input");

        newInput1.id = "itemId" + instance;

        newInput1.name = "itemId" + instance;

        newInput1.type = "text";

        newInput1.className = "form-control";

        newInput1.placeholder = "Item Id";

        event.target.onkeypress = null;
        newInput1.style.marginBottom = "5px";
        newInput1.style.marginTop = "5px";



        var newDiv1 = document.createElement("div");

        newDiv1.className = "col-md-4";

        newDiv1.appendChild(newInput1);


        var newDiv1Form = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv1Form.className = "form-group";

        newDiv1Form.appendChild(newDiv1);



        //item item one//   
        var newInput2 = document.createElement("input");

        newInput2.id = "itemNum" + instance;

        newInput2.name = "itemNum" + instance;

        newInput2.type = "text";

        newInput2.className = "form-control";

        newInput2.placeholder = "Item Num";

        event.target.onkeypress = null;

        newInput2.style.marginBottom = "5px";
        newInput2.style.marginTop = "5px";



        var newDiv2 = document.createElement("div");

        newDiv2.className = "col-md-7";

        newDiv2.appendChild(newInput2);




        newDiv1Form.appendChild(newDiv2);


        var newDiv1Row = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv1Row.className = "row";

        newDiv1Row.appendChild(newDiv1Form);

        cell1.appendChild(newDiv1Row);

        // cell1 ends here//

        //cell2 starts here but named as cell 3 //
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(1);

        var newInput3 = document.createElement("input");
        newInput3.id = "qty" + instance;
        newInput3.name = "qty" + instance;
        newInput3.type = "text";
        newInput3.className = "form-control";
        newInput3.placeholder = "Qty";
        newInput3.onkeypress = newTextBox;
        // Line added
        event.target.onkeypress = null;
        newInput3.style.marginBottom = "5px";
        newInput3.style.marginTop = "5px";

        var newDiv3 = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv3.className = "col-md-10";

        newDiv3.appendChild(newInput3);



        newDiv3form = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv3form.className = "form-group";

        newDiv3form.appendChild(newDiv3);

        newDiv3Row = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv3Row.className = "row";
        newDiv3Row.appendChild(newDiv3form);
        cell3.appendChild(newDiv3Row);

        //cell 2 ends here but cell 3 name is taken//

        //cell 3 starts here with cell 4 name//

        var cell4 = row.insertCell(2);

        var newInput4 = document.createElement("input");
        newInput4.id = "unitPrice" + instance;
        newInput4.name = "unitPrice" + instance;
        newInput4.type = "text";
        newInput4.className = "form-control";
        newInput4.placeholder = "Price(Rs)";
        newInput4.style.marginBottom = "5px";
        newInput4.style.marginTop = "5px";

        var newDiv4 = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv4.className = "col-md-10";

        newDiv4.appendChild(newInput4);



        newDiv4form = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv4form.className = "form-group";

        newDiv4form.appendChild(newDiv4);

        newDiv4Row = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv4Row.className = "row";
        newDiv4Row.appendChild(newDiv4form);
        cell4.appendChild(newDiv4Row);

        //cell 3 starts here with cell 4 name//

        //cell 4 starts here with cell 5 name//

        var cell5 = row.insertCell(3);

        var newInput5 = document.createElement("input");
        newInput5.id = "amountPrice" + instance;
        newInput5.name = "amountPrice" + instance;
        newInput5.type = "text";
        newInput5.className = "form-control";
        newInput5.placeholder = "Price(Rs)";
        newInput5.style.marginBottom = "5px";
        newInput5.style.marginTop = "5px";

        var newDiv5 = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv5.className = "col-md-10";

        newDiv5.appendChild(newInput5);



        newDiv5form = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv5form.className = "form-group";

        newDiv5form.appendChild(newDiv5);

        newDiv5Row = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv5Row.className = "row";
        newDiv5Row.appendChild(newDiv5form);
        cell5.appendChild(newDiv5Row);

        //cell 4 ends here with cell 5 name//

        //cell 5 ends here with cell 6 name//
        var cell6 = row.insertCell(4);
        var spanOne = document.createElement("span");

        spanOne.id = "spanOne" + instance;
        spanOne.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign col-md-offset-5";

        spanOne.style.lineHeight = "2.5";
        spanOne.style.marginBottom = "5px";
        spanOne.style.marginTop = "5px";
        spanOne.onclick = deleteRowOne;

        cell6.appendChild(spanOne);


    }


}

/*ends here for the dynamic page*/
</script>
```

This is the code where textbox is created dynamically. 
How could I pass the value from jsp to servlet

Comment: on some event, make a server side call to the `servlet` with textbox's value

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is passing the value from client side to server side.
You can Submit the value to server by using form submit or ajax.

Answer (score 0):

After adding textbox in you jsp if you want to move on servlet then simply u can dynamically submit form and include new text box in this form or you u can write ajax to get data from newly created text box to servlet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways

1. After creating those elements append it in your form and send data to Servlet through ajax call.

   ```
       var clone = document.createElement('INPUT');
          clone.type="text";
          clone = elem.cloneNode(true);
          clone.setAttribute("id", "file_"+index);
          clone.setAttribute("name", "file_"+index);
          $('#myform').append(clone);   
       var formData = new FormData($('#myform')[0]);
   and send this form data in your ajax call as below : 

   $.ajax({
               url : "ServletName" ,
               type : "POST",
               dataType : 'text',
               contentType : false,
               processData : false,
               cache : false,
               async: false,
               data : formData,
               success : function(response) {
                 $console.text('Successfully saved.');
               },
               error : function() {
                 $console.text("Failure");
               }
             });
   ```
2. Just send your extra fields as parameter to your servlet with &parametername=parametervalue

   var pvalue = document.getElementById("dynamicfield").value;

or

```
var pvalue = $("#dynamicfield").val();

$.ajax({
            url : "servletname?" + "&pname=" + pvalue,
            type : "POST",
            dataType : 'text',
            contentType : false,
            processData : false,
            cache : false,
            async: false,
            success : function(response) {
              $console.text('Successfully saved.');
            },
            error : function() {
              $console.text("failure");
            }
          });
```